# Why `inline-block` is still moved to next line even the width is just the same (or a little bit smaller)

Tags: html, css, css-float

As shown in the example, the two of 150px `div`s won't stay in the 300px parent div even if I set them as `inline-block`s.

Why would they occupy extra space?

There is no problem when using `float:left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/r2LLzwbu/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: You will find your answer in the link above. For future reference please include your code in the question itself. A JSFiddle alone is not suitable as the link may die making the question useless.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Thank you for your kind remind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the indentation causes extra spaces to appear in the div. To illustrate, if you change the HTML to a single line:

`<div class="outer"><div class="inner-1"></div><div class="inner-2"></div></div>`

it works. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2LLzwbu/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier explains this very well in one of his post here -

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

**To summarize what Chris said -**

The inline blocks are similar to independent words in a sentence. Inline-block carries the space in between them the way words do in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
.inner-1{
    background:green;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0;border:0;padding:0;

}
```

Remove `.inner-1` css `display:inline-block;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/r2LLzwbu/4/)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. The OP is asking why `inline-block` forces the blocks onto separate lines.